# aspnet core build slow only when publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core web app. If I click build -> Rebuild, it finishes in just under 15 seconds.

However, if I publish it (via web deploy to azure, FTP to azure, or even just a file system publish to a local folder), it takes a very long time. Over a half hour before I give up and cancel it.

What is different about publishing that could cause this? How can I diagnose this to make it go faster?

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but it spends a long time outputting messages like this:

> Added Item(s): 
>       ResolvedFileToPublish=
>           C:\filepath\bg6.jpg
>                   CopyToPublishDirectory=PreserveNewest
>                   RelativePath=wwwroot\images\bg6.jpg
>                   TargetPath=wwwroot\images\bg6.jpg

Comment: sometimes when this happens i try cleaning and emptying the server before publish

Comment: You'd better run `dotnet publish` with `-v` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21 and see if it is also slow.

Comment: Publish can take a long time if your App generates temp files and you don't remove these files regularly. Try to check 'Remove additional files at destination' on publish configuration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following two ways

1.Try disabling windows defender on the machines where publish is slow to see if it fixes the issue.You could have some exclusions to the real-time protection.

2.Make the following settings in your project：
**Tools-> Options-> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity**

[image]

Comment: ...Sigh. This fixed it. I can't believe how long I spent trying to fix this and waiting for for builds to complete for publishing. I didn't realize this would have such a dramatic effect on publishing build speeds but not regular build speeds. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Really strange solution... but seems to help, thanks! :)

Comment: Didn't work for me, windows defender is off and build out verbosity was already set to Minimal and yet publishes are still super slow.